# Does Titan's atmosphere contain breathable Oxygen?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

How did Tony Stark and Spider-Man survive on titan?

Tony Stark and Spider-Man both are normal human beings, so how can they survive on Titan without any oxygen and also with their power suits broken completely.

[image: Stark in space]

Comment: Why do you believe there is no oxygen on titan?

Comment: remember that Quill (Star Lord) is half human and i don't think his Celestial side allows him to be able to breath in any atmosphere

Comment: The fictional Titan is not the same as the moon of Saturn called Titan.

Comment: I changed the title, as its about the atmosphere, not whether they 'survive' some fight.  People are very sensitive about spoilers, even if there isn't one here.

Comment: @iandotkelly "People are very sensitive about spoilers" - then shouldn't the first picture be removed? That's just as much of a spoiler (and also completely irrelevant to the newly-reworded question)

Comment: @iandotkelly but isn't Tony & Peter being on Titan a spoiler in itself. This is getting way out of hand. Some strict guidelines need to be set to draw a firm line.

Comment: @F1Krazy The picture is within the post; spoilers are completely fine within questions. The issue is that question titles show up to people who don't want to know anything about the movie; either looking at this site, or the Hot Network questions on any other SE site. Even though "survive on Titan" is definitely not a spoiler, I could easily see someone seeing that and mis-reading it as giving away that those characters don't die (which wouldn't be correct anyway).

Comment: @KharoBangdo .... if you have a proposal for what the guidelines should be or how we should enforce them, please do open a question on Meta.  In reality every title is a potential spoiler.  Yes, knowing he goes to Titan tells you that he goes to Titan, it is a spoiler, but relatively innocuous, and the movie is now 3 weeks out .. so many people who are particularly sensitive to the details will have seen it.  Implying (correctly or not) that they survive or don't survive something is a much bigger potential issue.

Comment: We do ask that people don't show spoilers in titles, and I do spend a lot of time trying to reduce the level of spoilers in titles to recently opened movies that tend to make it to the Hot Network Questions list.

Comment: @F1Krazy ... we have a policy of removing spoilers from titles, particularly of recent movies.  If you've not seen Infinity War and start reading Q&A about it on here, then this is your own fault.

Answer (score 16):

> Tony Stark and spider-man both are normal human being so how can they survived on titan without any oxygen and also their power suit broke completely.

### Because Titan's atmosphere appears to be the exact same as Earth's.

Notice the blue skies and white clouds, the green plants, and the water. Since water consists of oxygen, and, since green plants contain chlorophyll (which contains oxygen), then, it's safe to assume Titan had extremely similar, if not the same, kind of atmosphere as Earth.

[image]

---

Other evidence that Titan is environmentally/atmospherically similar to Earth:

- Atmospheric temperature seems to be the same. I.e., nobody is sweating profusely or freezing cold while on Titan, which suggests that the temperature is within Earth's range of temps (or at least, for the duration of their time on Titan it is).

Comment: green plants and blue sky do not mean there will be oxygen.

Comment: @therichpost *"green plants and blue sky do not mean there will be oxygen."* -- I agree.. that by itself doesn't necessarily mean there's oxygen. However, **since we know Tony and Peter to be 100% human beings**, and, coupled with the fact that **literally nobody there had any issue freely breathing the atmosphere**, then, **the proposed evidence seems quite convincing to me**. Looking at the previous state of Titan, **there's no evidence that suggests otherwise**.

Comment: A counter example: __[Pandora](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Pandora#Atmosphere)__ from __[Avatar](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/)__. Just because there is a blue sky, water and plants the atmosphere can still contain gases that are toxic to humans. Is that water of the same composition as Earth water? Are those alien plants the same as Earth plants? - The atmosphere is breathable because Tony and Peter show no ill effects. That Titan once looked similar to Earth however does not prove that the air is breathable.

Comment: @Oliver_C They (The Directors) made it breathable,For the sole reason that a fight MUST commence in Titan. If they didn't, then the human avengers in Titan would have died.

Comment: Good answer, but the gravity is notably lighter on Titan. You can see Mantis bouncing around in the background, enjoying the lighter gravity while Tony, Strange, and Quill discuss the plan. There are also a couple of times during the fight when someone gets launched into the air and must be brought back down before they sail off into space.

Comment: @Omegacron Wasn't there a line about gravity fluctuations or something that explained the lighter gravity in some areas?  I only saw the movie once and it's been a few weeks :)

Comment: @Omegacron Ah, that was on Titan? I did remember Mantis jumping around, but couldn't recall which planet it was on (and if it was even from *IW*). Thanks for the comment, I'll make the edit.

Answer (score 2):

A theory could be that Tony & Peter take off their helmets once their suit AI detects(off-screen) that Titan has oxygen to breath. If there was no oxygen to breath they would continue using their helmets/masks.

Remember that when they crash land on Titan, both are wearing full suits with helmet/mask